# jQuery .hide() not undone by media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries

So, I have a layout that is 2up on wide monitors and then a list view on smaller monitors using media queries. Everything works really well except for I also have jQuery .show()/.hide()ing elements on the widescreen setup. **That** works well also, but when I resize my window: anything that jQuery has currently .hide()d does **not** show up, despite my media queries defining display: block; for those elements at that size.

The site in question is located [here](http://www.jessekeane.me), and the source is [on GitHub](https://github.com/jarofghosts/jk.me).

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you clarify what specific elements you are trying to hide / unhide? Because, I visited your site, and viewed it in both forms, and it appears to work as expected: double-view (widescreen), and list view (non wide-screen). Without knowing what specific elements you are trying to hide / unhide, any suggestions will merely be superficial.

Comment: Ah, sorry if it was unclear: the pages on the right, when cycled using the buttons at the top. When you do that and THEN resize, the pages that were shown then hidden are not visible. At least not in chrome.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and observed the same. It seems as though your problem might be a bug in the project itself. Aside from poking around in the source code itself, it may be a better idea to contact the original developer on Github and file a bug report.

Comment: Well, the project is my own and I just pointed to the repo so it would be easier to look through. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong and all the relevant google searches aren't turning anything up. Thanks for your time, though!

Comment: No problem. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: It's cool. I think I figured it out, anyway.. turns out I need a few strategic "!important"s. Let this be a lesson to anyone who finds this later.

Comment: Please post that as an answer instead. It would be much easier to understand that way.

Answer (score 3):

first of all jQuery replaces the style of the element you change, so no matter what's the previous CSS if you use:

```
$("#myelement").hide();
```

it will forcefully change the CSS display property, you have 2 options here.

1) Create a hidden class, this way you can create a media query for the class, so when the window is > 1000px it will have display:none; but if it have 1000< it can have display:block; using:

```
$("#myElement").addClass("hidden");
```

instead of hide().

2) Play with the resize() event of jQuery http://api.jquery.com/resize/ binded to the window, this way you can do this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width()> 1000){
        //Hide or show, or do some pirate stuff
    }else{
        //More pirate stuff
    }
});
```

I hope this was what you were looking for.